# How to get an IP address from a MAC address?

Tags: networking, ip-address, mac-address

I have an ipscanner, but not every device is showing up.

If I know a device is on the LAN, and I know its MAC address, how can I get it's IP address?

Comment: yep ... quintessence: there is no way to do it without doing the reverse.

Comment: It is a duplicate.  Sorry, I didn't find it by searching.

Comment: arp -a | find "<MAC address>"

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try `arp -a` and it will list out a table with ip address and their matched up MAC Ids. This may not work depending on how your lan is setup.

Comment: It won't work if the device has no IP address assigned.

Comment: @vonbrand - which is a suitable result since the OP is looking for IPs associated, if none then it's outside the range of the question.

Comment: Yes I agree with @vonbrand.
But since he says the device is on the lan meaning I assume it can communicated over lan implying it has an IP address! or can there be a case where a device does not have an IP address and yet communicated on the network?

Comment: @camelbrush Of course! There are a number of ethernet protocols which don't use IPs at all. They're not widely used anymore though, and they come from an era of private networking protocols before the Internet was really a 'thing'.

Comment: Sorry so long to answer...  the device is on the LAN (it is an important switch - a Dell PowerConnect 3548), but the `arp -a` command does not display an IP address for it, and so I can't access it's html interface.  I have a similar device of the same model that *does* have an IP address.  Using SoftPerfect NetScan, I can't see it's mac address in the list.  But I know the mac address from the back of the switch.